# How can I get this JQuery to target both forms on my page?

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I have the same form repeated twice on a landing page.

The form has 2 select boxes, if the first one has a value of "Parking" then the second one shows a list of prices.

If it shows a value of anything else.. then a different set of options are shown.

I currently have to write the code twice, but replace the form classes.

Can I do this in one go?

The selections do not need to mirror in each form, just function in the same way.

```
$( ".regprod" ).change(function() {
    var selected = $("select.regprod option:selected").val();
    if(selected === "Parking" || selected === ""){
        $(".forma .strg-price").hide().attr("required", false);
        $(".forma .park-price").show().attr("required", true);
    }
    else {
        $(".forma .strg-price").show().attr("required", true);
        $(".forma .park-price").hide().attr("required", false);
    }
});

$( ".regprod2" ).change(function() {
    var selected = $("select.regprod2 option:selected").val();
    if(selected === "Parking" || selected === ""){
        $(".formb .strg-price").hide().attr("required", false);
        $(".formb .park-price").show().attr("required", true);
    }
    else {
        $(".formb .strg-price").show().attr("required", true);
        $(".formb .park-price").hide().attr("required", false);
    }
});
```

Thanks, I have updated to this:

```
    $( ".regprod" ).change(function() {

    var $form = $(this).closest('form');

    var selected = $form.find("select.regprod option:selected").val();

    if(selected === "Parking" || selected === ""){
        $form.find(".strg-price").hide().prop("required", false);
        $form.find(".park-price").show().prop("required", true);
    }
    else {
        $form.find(".strg-price").show().prop("required", true);
        $form.find(".park-price").hide().prop("required", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Use a common class and any transversal method to target specific elements. Now you'd have better to post relevant HTML markup in order to get specific help. FYI, as `required` is a boolean attribute, it is preferred to use `.prop('required', true);`

Comment: A.Wolff's method is exactly what you need to do. If you can edit your question to include the HTML structure we can give you a more complete exampe of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about using .prop instead.

Comment: Thanks again, I cant select these comments as answers, and i have used what is mentioned in Bills 'Answer' so will select that as the answer once I can. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a comma in your selector.

```
$('.regprod,.regprod2').change()
```

Then, to target the form your on inside your script you can use `.closest()`.

```
var $form = $(this).closest('form');
```

Then do:

```
$form.find('.strg-price').stuff()
```

Comment: Good, but that's not it all. You also have to use `this` in place of things like `select.regprod2`

Comment: By doing this, the content of the function would change both forms anytime a change to one form was made.

Comment: Thanks, I am a little confused as to how i can select $forms selected option

Comment: You can just do `$form.find('select').val()` to get the selected value.